# org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.entity.RestNode cannot be cast to Spring Data Neo4j Node Entity in SDN 3

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

Not able to typecast RestNode to Neo4j Node Entity.
Using MapResult has also been deprecated in Spring Data Neo4j version 3. What should be the right way to convert?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still needing the answer, but I'm using the Neo4jOperations.convert method, pretty straight forward conversion:

```
T convertedEntity = Neo4jOperations.convert(Object value, Class<T> type);
```